# text mining with tm package in R ,remove words starting from [http] or any other specifc word

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, word-cloud, metacharacters

I am new to R and text mining. I had made a word cloud out of twitter feed related to some term. The problem that I'm facing is that in the wordcloud it shows http:... or htt...
How do I deal about this issue
I tried using metacharacter * but I still doubt if I'm applying it right

> tw.text = removeWords(tw.text,c(stopwords("en"),"rt","http\\*"))

somebody into text-minning please help me with this.

Comment: You could just use `gsub` to your original data. Please post a little piece of your data, text to remove and desired output.

Comment: I was trying to fetch some tweets
`head(tweets,10)
 [1] "@amitkumarpatil2 @bdutt yes.\nhttp://t.co/6v2n4EHeoc" @mihirssharma http://t.co/WHnaJmUNNG"           
 [7] "RT @QLDMackay: Cheap power or clean energy? Modi's $275 billion Indian dilemma http://t.co/YEaaHodO6p ... https://t.co/zfV2XRKwfl" `
So, they include URL's to news pages etc

Comment: I tried gsub() too, but it only removes "http:" rest URL //xyz.com still remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to remove URLs from your string, you may use:

```
gsub("(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+", "", x)
```

Where `x` would be:

```
x <- c("some text http://idontwantthis.com", 
         "same problem again http://pleaseremoveme.com")
```

---

It would be easier to provide you with a specific answer if you could post sample of your data but the following example would give you a clean text with no URLs:

```
> clean_x <- gsub("(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+", "", x)
> clean_x
[1] "some text "          "same problem again "
```

*As a side point, I would suggest that it may be worth searching for the existing methods to clean text before mining. For example the `clean` function discussed [here](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/quanteda/man/clean.html) would enable you to do this automatically. On similar lines, there are function to clean your text from tweets (`#`,`@`), punctuation and other undesirable entries.*

Comment: Great, `clean(X, removeURL=TRUE)` worked just fine (y)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the below code to corpus to replace a string pattern with space.
String pattern can be urls or terms you want to remove from the wordcloud.
For example to remove terms starting with https:

## replace with space

> toSpace = content_transformer( function(x, pattern)  gsub(pattern," ",x) )
>
> tweet_corpus_clean = tm_map( tweet_corpus,  toSpace, "https*")

## Or pass a pattern as below to remove urls

> tweet_corpus_clean  =  tm_map( tweet_corpus,  toSpace, "(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+")